# Power Query transform a table with date ranges into daily

Tags: powerquery

I am using Power Query to solve the following problem:
need to create a daily split of data based on a range of dates.

I have a table with ad campaign results. Each line is a campaign with Index as ID. It has a start date, end date (or a duration) and some numeric fields, in this case AdRequests and Spend.
For each line, it's a total for the number days in Duration column.

What I need to do is un-summarise this into daily data. Populate a daily data out of it with values of spend etc being a daily average. N.B. number of campaigns varies from project to project, it needs to be dynamic

i.e. this is my input table

[image]

and here is what i want it to be. This is example for 1st campaign only, but the table needs to have all of them, and that varies from project to project.

[image]

I have to deliver this tomorrow, and so far my search hasn't yielded anything remotely good.
thank you for any ideas, in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I did it.

1. Add a custom column with the formula = {1..[Duration]}
2. Expand the custom column
3. Change start date to number type
4. Add a custom column with the formula = [Start Date] + [Custom] -1
5. Change start date back to a date type column
6. Delete unnecessary columns
7. Rename columns

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Index", Int64.Type}, {"Start Date", type datetime}, {"Ad Requests", Int64.Type}, {"Spend", Int64.Type}, {"Duration", Int64.Type}, {"Daily Adrequests", Int64.Type}, {"Daily Spend", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each {1..[Duration]}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Start Date", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Custom.1", each [Start Date] + [Custom] -1),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom1",{{"Custom.1", type date}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Changed Type2",{"Index", "Custom.1", "Start Date", "Ad Requests", "Spend", "Duration", "Daily Adrequests", "Daily Spend", "Custom"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Start Date", "Ad Requests", "Spend", "Duration"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Before/After

[image: Before/After]

Comment: lovely!! it worked great, and i learnt a neat trick. thanks a lot )